# Feature selection using RFE in SVM kernel (other than linear eg rbf, poly etc)

Tags: svm, feature-selection

At [this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html), there is an example of finding feature ranking using RFE in SVM linear kernel.

If I want to check feature ranking in other SVM kernel (eg. rbf, poly etc).**How to do it?**

I have changed the kernel in the code from **SVR(kernel="linear") to SVR(kernel="rbf")**,

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.svm import SVR
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFE(estimator, 5, step=1)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
selector.ranking_
```

and then I get this error

```
ValueError: coef_ is only available when using a linear kernel
```

**Question: How to check feature ranking in other SVM kernels eg rbf, poly etc?**

Answer (score 9):

To use RFE, it is a must to have a supervised learning estimator which attribute coef_ is available, this is the case of the linear kernel. The error you are getting is because coef_ is not for SVM using kernels different from Linear. It is in [RFE documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html)

A walk-around solution is presented in [**Feature selection for support vector machines with RBF kernel**](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Quanzhong_Liu/publication/220637867_Feature_selection_for_support_vector_machines_with_RBF_kernel/links/557ea92508aeea18b777e492.pdf) by Quanzhong Liu et. al.

Comment: I dont understand what was the the point of giving -ve points on this question. I am clearly asking how to check feature ranking in other SVM kernels (which are not linear)